# Errors in nls() - singular gradient or NaNs produced

Tags: r, non-linear-regression

I am trying to fit my photosynthesis data to a nls function, which is a nonrectangular hyperbola function. So far, I have some issues with getting the right start value for nls and, therefore, I am getting a lot of errors such as 'singular gradient ', 'NaNs produced', or 'step factor 0.000488281 reduced below 'minFactor' of 0.000976562'. Would you please give some suggestions for finding the best starting values? Thanks in advance!

The codes and data are below:

```
#Dataframe
PPFD <- c(0,0,0,50,50,50,100,100,100,200,200,200,400,400,400,700,700,700,1000,1000,1000,1500,1500,1500)
Cultivar <- c(-0.7,-0.8,-0.6,0.6,0.5,0.8,2.0,2.0,2.3,3.6,3.7,3.7,5.7,5.5,5.8,9.7,9.6,10.0,14.7,14.4,14.9,20.4,20.6,20.9)
NLRC <-data.frame(PPFD,Cultivar)

#nls regression
reg_nrh <- nls(Cultivar ~ (1/(2*Theta))*(AQY*PPFD+Am-sqrt((AQY*PPFD+Am)^2-4*AQY*Theta*Am*PPFD))-Rd, data = NLRC, start=list(Am = max(NLRC$Cultivar)-min(NLRC$Cultivar), AQY = 0.05, Rd=-min(NLRC$Cultivar), Theta = 1))

#estimated parameters for plotting
Amnrh <- coef(reg_nrh)[1]
AQYnrh <- coef(reg_nrh)[2]
Rdnrh <- coef(reg_nrh)[3]
Theta <- coef(reg_nrh)[4]

#plot
plot(NLRC$PPFD, NLRC$Cultivar, main = c("Cultivar"), xlab="", ylab="", ylim=c(-2,40),cex.lab=1.2,cex.axis=1.5,cex=2)+mtext(expression("PPFD ("*mu*"mol photons "*m^-2*s^-1*")"),side=1,line=3.3,cex=1.5)+mtext(expression(P[net]*" ("*mu*"mol "*CO[2]*" "*m^-2*s^-1*")"),side=2,line=2.5,cex=1.5)

#simulated value
ppfd = seq(from = 0, to = 1500)
pnnrh <- (1/(2*Theta))*(AQYnrh*ppfd+Amnrh-sqrt((AQYnrh*ppfd+Amnrh)^2-4*AQYnrh*Theta*Amnrh*ppfd))- Rdnrh
lines(ppfd, pnnrh, col="Green")
```

Answer (score 1):

If we

1. take the maximum of 0 and the expression within the sqrt to avoid taking negative square roots
2. fix Theta at 0.8
3. use lm to get starting values for AQY and Am

then it converges

```
Theta <- 0.8
fm <- lm(Cultivar ~ PPFD, NLRC)
st <- list(AQY = coef(fm)[[2]], Rd = -min(NLRC$Cultivar), Am = coef(fm)[[1]])
fo <- Cultivar ~ 
  (1/(2*Theta))*(AQY*PPFD+Am-sqrt(pmax(0, (AQY*PPFD+Am)^2-4*AQY*Theta*Am*PPFD)))-Rd
reg <- nls(fo, data = NLRC, start = st)

deviance(reg)  # residual sum of squares
## [1] 5.607943

plot(Cultivar ~ PPFD, NLRC)
lines(fitted(reg) ~ PPFD, NLRC, col = "red")
```

(continued after image)
[image: screenshot]

Note that the first model below has only two parameters yet has lower residual sum of squares  (lower is better).

```
reg2 <- nls(Cultivar ~ a * PPFD^b, NLRC, start = list(a = 1, b = 1))
deviance(reg2)
## [1] 5.098796
```

These have higher residual sum of squares but do have the advantage that they are very simple.

```
deviance(fm) # fm defined above
## [1] 6.938648

fm0 <- lm(Cultivar ~ PPFD + 0, NLRC) # same as fm except no intercept
deviance(fm0)
## [1] 7.381632
```

Comment: Thank you for the nice explanation on my question! Although the theta should be 0.8~0.9, I think I can find suitable starting values based on your advice. Really appreciate it!

Comment: Have modified it to fix Theta at 0.8 (although fixing it to Theta = -2 actually gives a smaller residual sum of squares).

Comment: Eventually, instead of using the fixed theta, I made a vector containing seq of 'theta' in the range of interest (0.8 to 0.99) and used them as an index for a 'for loop' to find the best theta value based on the result of AIC. The estimated theta resulted in not only quite a good fitting in the plot but also a better statistic result. I appreciate your code and advice to help me think this approach!